# Getting 0 from bundle in Android

Tags: android, bundle

I have a recyclerview which when clicked goes to their corresponding activities.I passed their position by binding them using bundle and then putting it in an intent .I retreive the data from the respective classes  .Each of these activities have viewpager in it.So I place that position in the `ImagePagerAdapter` object created in the activities.The images are perfectly loaded in the viewpager.I have a button in these activities which goes to a different activity and when I try to  navigate back to the activity but 
the application craashes.Here is the error that appears:
Error:

```
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc.NandFragment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:153)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc.NandFragment.onCreate(NandFragment.java:66)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:153) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
01-27 03:40:40.220 5043-5043/com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

RecyclerAdapter.java:

```
    itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = getAdapterPosition();
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AranyaFragment.class);
                    Bundle a = new Bundle();
                    a.putInt("Aranya", position);
                    intent.putExtras(a);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, BolgattyFragment.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("Bolg", position);
                    intent1.putExtras(b);
                    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MascotFragment.class);
                    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    Bundle c = new Bundle();
                    c.putInt("Mas", position);
                    intent2.putExtras(c);
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, WaterScapes.class);
                    Bundle d = new Bundle();
                    d.putInt("Water", position);
                    intent3.putExtras(d);
                    intent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, SamudraFragment.class);
                    Bundle e = new Bundle();
                    e.putInt("Samudra", position);
                    intent4.putExtras(e);
                    intent4.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Intent intent5 = new Intent(context, GoldenFragment.class);
                    Bundle f = new Bundle();
                    f.putInt("Gold", position);
                    intent5.putExtras(f);

                    intent5.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Intent intent6 = new Intent(context, RainFragment.class);
                    Bundle g = new Bundle();
                    g.putInt("Rain", position);
                    intent6.putExtras(g);
                    intent6.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent6);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Intent intent7 = new Intent(context, PeriyarFragment.class);
                    Bundle h = new Bundle();
                    h.putInt("Periyar", position);
                    intent7.putExtras(h);
                    intent7.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent7);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Intent intent8 = new Intent(context, PepperFragment.class);
                    Bundle i = new Bundle();
                    i.putInt("Pepper", position);
                    intent8.putExtras(i);
                    intent8.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent8);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Intent intent9 = new Intent(context, NandFragment.class);
                    Bundle j = new Bundle();
                    j.putInt("Nand", position);
                    intent9.putExtras(j);
                    intent9.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent9);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    Intent intent10 = new Intent(context, TamarFragment.class);
                    Bundle k = new Bundle();
                    k.putInt("Tamar", position);
                    intent10.putExtras(k);
                    intent10.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent10);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`NandFragment.java`(Not actually a frament):In the below code I retrieve the position by using

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras(); 
pos= b.getInt("Nand");
```

The button goes to another activity and when I try to return back the app crashes.The error is at

```
pos= b.getInt("Nand");

public class NandFragment extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nandanamlayout);
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        pos= b.getInt("Nand");
        Button button1;
        button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.nrrooms);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NandRooms.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpfragment9);

        ImagePagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new ImagePagerAdapter(this,pos);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ParallaxPageTransformer());}}
```

NandRooms.java:

```
public class NandRooms extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rooms);
  Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.rooms);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Rooms");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}}
```

If you haven't understood it please tell me...

Comment: Format first part of your question. It isn't readable.

Comment: Edited please look into it

Comment: ....you need to post your `onOptionsItemSelected` method where you **actually** handle UP navigation. -_-

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you hit the Up button, you aren't sending any extras like when you first navigated to the NandFragment Activity. So when you go back to the Activity using the Up button, `getIntent().getExtras()` will return null, since there are no Extras that have been sent. The way to handle this is to override the Up action button, then handle the "back navigation" yourself, inserting your extras along the way. To do this, you need to Override `onOptionsItemSelected()` and look for the `android.R.id.home` action. Then you would do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, NandFragment.class);
            //put in your extras here...
            startActivity(upIntent);

            //return true to let the OS know you handled this action yourself
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think he is using UP navigation?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Because in his original post, he mentioned hitting a "back" button on the toolbar, which is the up button. It appears he edited this part out now.

Comment: I am now editing the question.I will post the Activity from which I handle the up button.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe I added the above code.But I am stuck with the same  error.

Comment: @jobin - Did you actually add in the extras where I said `//put in your extras here...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Before you get extra value always check if you have it first otherwise if it doesn't exist you will get error.

```
   if (getIntent().hasExtra("Nand")) {
       Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
       pos= b.getInt("Nand");
   }
   else{
       Log.d("TAG", "Bundle is not set");
   }
```